# Inbox messages and Achievements of a closed beta site still shown

Tags: bug, android-app, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

I was Active in Arabic SE before it was closed days ago. Though I still see messages and achievements in my inbox that's related to it.

In deleted questions, all go hidden and that's good. Why not doing the same for Closed sites?

[image]

because this, the Android app is getting crash at every time I check inbox or achievements.